# Recyclerview as Snappy Gallery

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I've been trying to figure this out on my own, but no chance.

What I need is the `RecyclerView` (horizontal scrolling) to always show 3 items. And whenever the user flings or scrolls left and right, it should snap to the next 3 items, if there are any more. I'm just looking for the simplest solution if there's any.

I have found Gallery solutions with a single item, but I need 3 items. I know it must be possible but I couldn't really figure out how. For one, the `LayoutManager` should calculate the item width to match it with the width of the device. And I guess I need to use a `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` somehow.

Anyone can help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar use case and I got good results using the suggestions in this SO thread:

[Snappy scrolling in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370289/snappy-scrolling-in-recyclerview)

The upshot is: use a custom RecyclerView.OnScrollListener to detect when the scroll state changes to SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, at which point use a subclass of LayoutManager which implements getFixScrollPos() to compute and then scroll to the correct position, snapping in the process.

I was also able to use a styleable attribute to set the number of items in the row at design time. You may want to do this as well.

Answer (score 7):

With [`LinearSnapHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearSnapHelper.html), this is now very easy.

All you need to do is this:

```
SnapHelper helper = LinearSnapHelper();
helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

It's that simple! Note that `LinearSnapHelper` was added in the Support Library starting from version 24.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in assuming that each page of the gallery is a vertical list of 3 items?

Call `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` within your override of `LayoutManager.onMeasure(Recycler, int, int, int)` to get the actual size of the recycler. You can then use that in `onLayoutChildren()` to figure out how large the children should be.

As for scrolling to the next views, I'm not entirely sure. Maybe add a custom `OnScrollListener` to the `RecyclerView` like in [RecyclerView horizontal snap in center](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29134094/3934789)?