# RecycleView limit fling speed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to limit the fling speed of the `recycleview`.

I see `RecycleView` has this method:

```
public boolean fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
...
}
```

However this deals with an internal private class `ViewFlinger`. Not to mention only called once with the initial velocities.

I also noticed there's an `OnFlingListener` which has both arguments: `velocityX`, `velocityY`. If you set this and return true from the method, fling wont work at all:

```
recycleView.setOnFlingListener(new RecyclerView.OnFlingListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But this is not what I want. I want neither.

I'd like to cap the top speed of the fling but still keep it going.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: So overriding of the fling method doesn't help? I mean you can extend RecycleView and override method like:
public boolean fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
  super.fling(Math.Min(velocityX, 1000), Math.Min(velocityY, 1000));
}

Comment: I had the same problem and this answer did the trick
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47596874/8647537