# Zoom central image recycler view

Tags: android, zooming, android-recyclerview, carousel

I have RecyclerView with images. It based on [this solution](http://www.plattysoft.com/2015/06/16/snapping-items-on-a-horizontal-list/). Images are lazy loaded into view with Glide. I need to add zoom on central image like in this:
[image: example]

How can i do it?

Comment: try this  http://www.plattysoft.com/2015/06/16/snapping-items-on-a-horizontal-list/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The most direct way to affect what you want is to extend `LinearLayoutManager`.
As you've no doubt discovered, hooking into the scroll events properly is a pain:

So let's extend the manager.  We'll create a few parameters that you might expose.

```
 public class ZoomCenterCardLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
   // Shrink the cards around the center up to 50%
   private final float mShrinkAmount = 0.5f;
   // The cards will be at 50% when they are 75% of the way between the
   // center and the edge.
   private final float mShrinkDistance = 0.75f;
```

Fill out your constructors, and then override `scrollHorizontallyBy`:

```
   @Override 
   public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, 
      RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
```

Call the parent's version and save the distance travelled.  We'll need to return this at the end of the method:

```
      int scrolled = super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state);
```

We are going to set up a simple linear interpolation.  It looks nice enough.

```
      float midpoint = getWidth() / 2.f;
      float d0 = 0.f;
      float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
      float s0 = 1.f;
      float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
```

Loop through all of the active children of the control, run the interpolation, and set the scale of the child.

```
      for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        float childMidpoint = 
           (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2.f;
        float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
        float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
        child.setScaleX(scale);
        child.setScaleY(scale);
      }

      return scrolled;
   }
```

This is almost all you need.  One final step is to make sure that this adjustment is called after initialization -- otherwise the zooming won't take effect until the first time the control is moved:

```
   @Override
   public void onLayoutChildren(Recycler recycler, State state) {
     super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
     scrollHorizontallyBy(0, recycler, state);
   }

 }
```

And that's all there is to it.  Super responsive, and you can drop this new layout manager into any horizontal recycler.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Found one more solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30041459/5571200

Comment: i made this, but it don't gives me the wanted result  
https://gist.github.com/beersheba/cdb69cf600d2d1b9f3c5  
`float scale = interp(Math.abs(myMidpoint - recyclerMidpoint));`  
And what is `interp` here?

Comment: `interp` represents an interpolating function that takes a number and returns some scale that will go from 0.0f to 1.0f (and possibly larger).  What you are passing is a distance that will most likely be in the 10s or 100s.  Not what you want.  I'll edit the answer to give you an example interpolation function that you can use.

Comment: also need to add some smoothScroll. zoom is working, but doing it discrete, not smooth.

Comment: I was unhappy with the direction I was sending you.  I changed the approach to override the layout manager directly.  I know I said it was a pain, but I was away on vacation.  Once I got home, I coded it up quickly to make sure it looked nice.  It was easier than I thought, and since I could actually test it, I felt more confident posting actual code.  I would not bother with the scroll hooks.

Comment: @MichaelHays What if I wanted to have a peek of the next item? How incorporate that?

Comment: how do you keep all child views Height and width same leaving the focused one?

Comment: Is it possible to start from the center item instead of the start point? Can scrollVerticallyBy(0, recycler, state) "0" value be the center of the recyclcerView item instead of zero? I opened a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52317646/start-my-recyclerview-horizontal-carousel-from-the-center-item

Comment: To start with first item centered horizontally you can add padding at start and end:

padding = (screenWith - itemWidth)/2

and set android:clipToPadding="false" to RecyclerView.

Comment: USE THIS: https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView . It's awesome

Comment: Thanks @HF_ for suggesting DiscreteScrollView, this did help me alot !!!