# Recycler view - resizing item view while scrolling (for carousel like effect)

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I need to create a vertical recyclerview in which item view in center of the screen should be resized to have zoom like effect while scrolling.

Things I have tried but didn't work :

1. Adding a scroll listener and looping through item views by position, measuring the centered position then updating `LayoutParams` of centered `view`.

   - `RecyclerView` won't let compute the position of items or update view while scrolling. It throws `IllegalStateException` if such operations are performed in `onScrolled`
2. Changing `LayoutParams` of centered item view in `onScrollStateChanged` while scrolling state is `IDLE` or `SETTLING`.

   - That only updates view after scroll has been/is going to be completed, not during scrolling on items is being performed.
3. The last option remained is implementing own custom `LayoutManager` that would extend default `LayoutManager`.

   - As far as I know, implementing custom `Layoutmanager` involves dealing with a lot more complex computations that needs to handled.

**Any other solutions or ideas will be appreciated.**

Comment: Hey @Krupal Shah can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952965/recyclerview-horizontal-scrolling-to-left?noredirect=1#comment87858720_49952965

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I found [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35311728/3830694), which did the exact same thing horizontally. Answer provides a working solution that extends `LinearLayoutManager`. I modified it a bit for also adapting vertical lists and it works. If there is any mistake in implementation, let me know in comments. Cheers!

Custom Layout Manager :

```
public class CenterZoomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

    private final float mShrinkAmount = 0.15f;
    private final float mShrinkDistance = 0.9f;

    public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }


    @Override
    public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int orientation = getOrientation();
        if (orientation == VERTICAL) {
            int scrolled = super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy, recycler, state);
            float midpoint = getHeight() / 2.f;
            float d0 = 0.f;
            float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
            float s0 = 1.f;
            float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                float childMidpoint =
                        (getDecoratedBottom(child) + getDecoratedTop(child)) / 2.f;
                float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
                float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
                child.setScaleX(scale);
                child.setScaleY(scale);
            }
            return scrolled;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        int orientation = getOrientation();
        if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            int scrolled = super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state);

            float midpoint = getWidth() / 2.f;
            float d0 = 0.f;
            float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
            float s0 = 1.f;
            float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                float childMidpoint =
                        (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2.f;
                float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
                float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
                child.setScaleX(scale);
                child.setScaleY(scale);
            }
            return scrolled;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

With horizontal orientation : 
[image]

with vertical orientation :

[image]

Comment: do you know, How to make it cyclic?? I have horizontal recyclerview with 10 items. I want to scroll it infinity. i.e position 1 will come again after completion of all items.

Comment: @RonakThakkar I think tricks like this will work : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45114415/3830694

Comment: @Krupal, did you ever figure out how to include peeks for the next scrollable item?

Comment: @KrupalShah, thanks for this solution but this doesn't seem to work for different mobile screen size. I have tested this with different screen sizes and in some devices left and right items appears perfect and in some devices it doesn't. Am talking about horizontal lists here.

Comment: @MohammedFarhan It seems working for me. You can modify it by yourself though.

Comment: Hi bro small issue in this first loading all the items are showing how to set second item visible

Comment: @Rameshsambu Maybe you could call layoutManager.scroll... methods programmatically.

Comment: @KrupalShah How to make the first item visible in the center?

Comment: @KrupalShah can you post the way to do stacking items transformation for recyclerview

Comment: @JyotiJK What does 'stacking items transformation' mean?

Comment: @KrupalShah like depth page transformation in viewpager.

Comment: thanks for the great answer, is it possible for you to tell me how I can make the center item bigger than yours? it's not quite what I want to achieve and I don't know which value I should change to achieve that.

Comment: @ArashAfsharpour I am not actively working on Android. Try playing with ShrinkAmount maybe.

Comment: This answer has an issue in initial state. check there https://stackoverflow.com/a/35311728