# Change scales of horizontal recycler view item on scrolling

Tags: android-recyclerview

I want to a recycler view like below image. Means I want to max height and width of middle recycler view item in a horizontal recycler view.

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution to that?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41307581/2717821

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a solution from a link, you may follow it accordingly.

```
public class CenterZoomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

 private final float mShrinkAmount = 0.15f;
 private final float mShrinkDistance = 0.9f;

public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}


@Override
public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int orientation = getOrientation();
    if (orientation == VERTICAL) {
        int scrolled = super.scrollVerticallyBy(dy, recycler, state);
        float midpoint = getHeight() / 2.f;
        float d0 = 0.f;
        float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
        float s0 = 1.f;
        float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            float childMidpoint =
                    (getDecoratedBottom(child) + getDecoratedTop(child)) / 2.f;
            float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
            float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
            child.setScaleX(scale);
            child.setScaleY(scale);
        }
        return scrolled;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int orientation = getOrientation();
    if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
        int scrolled = super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state);

        float midpoint = getWidth() / 2.f;
        float d0 = 0.f;
        float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
        float s0 = 1.f;
        float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            float childMidpoint =
                    (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2.f;
            float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
            float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
            child.setScaleX(scale);
            child.setScaleY(scale);
        }
        return scrolled;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

}