# How to stop scrolling as half item can be visible in HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, layout, horizontalscrollview

Can you plz share any suggestion or library to achieve below,

[image]

e.g. If you see in Google Play Store, when you scroll `HorizontalScrollView`, your scrolling will stop as half of the next item user can able to see. App forcefully stops scroll like this so the user gets to know, there are more items available.

I do not have any code to share. I just want your hints/libs.

Thank you!

Comment: its **recyclerview** my friend not **HorizontalScrollView**

Comment: @Prem I know, but plz read my explained problem again. I want to stop scrolling as half of the next item user can able to see

Comment: you didn't mention about recyclerview in your question that why i give that comment

Comment: try this http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/06/carousel-layout-with-viewpager-in.html

Comment: try this with recyclerview  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307578/recycler-view-resizing-item-view-while-scrolling-for-carousel-like-effect

Comment: I think you are looking for SnapHelper in recycleview

Comment: @Burhanuddin Rashid...Thanks buddy..its exactly i m looking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `Snaphelper` in `RecycleView` its available in support libraries
You can attached `SnapHelper` like this

```
SnapHelper startSnapHelper = new StartSnapHelper();
startSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(yourRecyclerView);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this task via using Horizontal recycler view and by adding pull to refresh technique. Set limited amount of items to be displayed by default and load on demand. Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can change item's width dynamically based on device's width to manage this scenario.

```
horizontalScrollView.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
                // based on this width, the space between the children and their
                // widths calculate new widths so you get a half clipped
                // children on the right side.
            }
        });
```