# Animation like facebook reactions on a Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-animation

Developing an application in which there is a recyclerview with some cardsviews. On each card there are some images,textviews and relative layout that I would like to apply a facebook-like effect when touched.

[Facebook reactions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5EKi.gif)

- When you touch the screen, the card will expand, and the others will stay side by side at their original size.
- When you take your finger off the screen, the card will return to its original size.

What I have so far:

```
//rv
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false)
        //layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
```

Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<Content> lista;


    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Content> lista) {
        this.context = context;
        this.lista = lista;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int position) {
        Content content = lista.get(position);

        if (!content.getTitulo().isEmpty()) {
            myViewHolder.titulo.setText(content.getTitulo);
        }

        if (!noticia.getThumb().isEmpty()) {
            Glide.with(context).load(content.getThumb()).into(myViewHolder.imageThumb);
        }

        if (!content.getIcone().isEmpty()) {
            Glide.with(context).load(content.getIcone()).into(myViewHolder.icone);
        }

        if (!content.getDescricao().isEmpty()) {
            myViewHolder.textDescricao.setText(content.getDescricao());
        }

        if (!content.getData().isEmpty()) {
            myViewHolder.data.setText(content.getData());
        }

        if (!content.getUrl().isEmpty()) {
            myViewHolder.url = content.getUrl();
        }

        if (!content.getNomeSite().isEmpty()) {


            myViewHolder.nomeSite.setText(content.getNomeSite());
        }

        myViewHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"OnLongClick",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
```

How can I make this effect?

Comment: Did you actually make that effect? The one in the link you provided. If so, could you share source code. I am looking to develop the same behavior but not able to start off

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a library for that. Here are some of them:

[Carousel Recyclerview](https://medium.com/@supahsoftware/custom-android-views-carousel-recyclerview-7b9318d23e9a)

[Carousel Recyclerview 2](http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/11/making-carousel-layout-in-android.html)

Or you can use this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41307581/12032861) answer