# Start my RecyclerView Horizontal Carousel from the center item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-scroll, linearlayoutmanager

I'm creating a carousel Horizontal RecyclerView with Zoom on focused item that is starting from the first item of the RecyclerView.

**Code for custom CenterZoomLayoutManager:**

```
public class CenterZoomLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {
private final float mShrinkAmount = 0.15f;
private final float mShrinkDistance = 0.9f;

public CenterZoomLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
}

@Override
public int scrollHorizontallyBy(int dx, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int orientation = getOrientation();
    if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {

        int scrolled = super.scrollHorizontallyBy(dx, recycler, state);
        float midpoint = getWidth() / 2.f;
        float d0 = 0.f;
        float d1 = mShrinkDistance * midpoint;
        float s0 = 1.f;
        float s1 = 1.f - mShrinkAmount;
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            float childMidpoint =
                    (getDecoratedRight(child) + getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2.f;
            float d = Math.min(d1, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint));
            float scale = s0 + (s1 - s0) * (d - d0) / (d1 - d0);
            child.setScaleX(scale);
            child.setScaleY(scale);
        }
        return scrolled;
    } else return 0;
}

@Override
public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
    scrollHorizontallyBy(0, recycler, state);
}
}
```

And in my `Fragment`, I have the following:

```
private void onSetRecyclerView() {

    recyclerView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    if (recyclerView != null) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new CenterZoomLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                false);

        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(storeList.size() / 2);

        final SnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I want to start my RecyclerView from the **center item** and not from the start position.

**Culprit:**
in my `CenterZoomLayoutManager`, I'm setting the pixel offset start to **0 pixels** through `scrollHorizontallyBy(0, recycler, state)`.

**Problem:**
I cannot find a way to pass the offset pixels created by `recyclerView.scrollToPosition(storeList.size() / 2)` to the `CenterZoomLayoutManager`. I tried to search for different built-in method to get the X-offset, but so far no luck.

Comment: can you help me understand the math behind this ?

Comment: I posted this almost 2 years ago. I don't freshly remember the mathematical logic, but I can tell you that I did not write this. I copied it from somewhere else. You can copy part of it, and search the net. You will be able to find the original post. As far as the result, I achieved having my layout centered in the middle, and not being close to the horizontal left or right edges of screen after @Cheticamp answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to change the timing of when `LinearSnapHelper` is attached to the `RecyclerView`. The following is a reworked `onSetRecyclerView()` that will snap the central item of the `RecyclerView` to the center of the screen. Notice that the `LinearSnapHelper` is not attached until the `RecyclerView` is laid out and scrolled appropriately. You do not need to do any scrolling in `onLayoutChildren()`.

```
private void onSetRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    CenterZoomLayoutManager layoutManager =
        new CenterZoomLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Scroll to the position we want to snap to
    layoutManager.scrollToPosition(storeList.size() / 2);
    // Wait until the RecyclerView is laid out.
    recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Shift the view to snap  near the center of the screen.
            // This does not have to be precise.
            int dx = (recyclerView.getWidth() - recyclerView.getChildAt(0).getWidth()) / 2;
            recyclerView.scrollBy(-dx, 0);
            // Assign the LinearSnapHelper that will initially snap the near-center view.
            LinearSnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();
            snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }
    });
}
```

This is how the initial screen of my test app is displayed. There are 201 "stores."

[image]

Comment: Why are you using index zero for getChildAt() though?

Comment: @RedM `layoutManager.scrollToPosition(storeList.size() / 2)` will do just enough to get the central view to the screen. In the `RecyclerView`, this will be the first child or the child at index 0.