# How to make an item in a ScrollView be positioned in the center of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have three `CardView` in a `HorizontalScrollView` and I want the middle one to be in the center of the screen (as if the user had swiped to get to it). How do I do that in `XML` or programmatically?

XML layout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/culture_toolbar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/beach_bg_placeholder" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/beach_bg_placeholder" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/beach_bg_placeholder" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

This is the result I'm going for:

[image: I want the upper half the mockup]

Comment: You should just use a `ViewPager`, or `RecyclerView` with `SnapHelper`

Comment: O, you fancy? :-)

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk i managed to create the same layout with a `ViewPager` and an `Adapter` for it and i now have the required functionality. My only issue though, is that i can't seem to be able to make the other 2 `CardView` objects show on the sides like in the image. Right now i can only see the selected one and i have to scroll to see any part of the other two cards. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23356010/4745241). But honestly I think it would work way better with recyclerview with pagersnaphelper.

Comment: Thank you very much, that link worked perfectly. Would you mind posting all of our conversation here as an answer with the links so that i can select it and award the rep?

Comment: @ErnestZamelczyk the bounty expires tomorrow and i'd like to give it to you since you were correct and so helpful. Please post your answer

Comment: oops. Didn't notice your comment until now. Too bad :p I'm glad that you got it working though. That's all that counts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do i do that in xml preferably?

AFAIK using `XML` only that is not possible

> How to make an item in a ScrollView be positioned in the center of the screen

I would suggest that you should use `carousel layout` instead of using `HorizontalScrollView`

You can make [`carousel layout` using `ViewPager` and using `RecyclerView`](https://i.imgur.com/YlmlH06.gif)

Check out below good articles for `carousel layout`

- [Carousel Layout with ViewPager in Android](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/06/carousel-layout-with-viewpager-in.html)
- [Android ViewPager - Show preview of page on left and right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10098040/7666442)
- [Carousel Layout with RecyclerView](https://medium.com/@supahsoftware/custom-android-views-carousel-recyclerview-7b9318d23e9a)
- [Making Carousel Layout in Android](http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/11/making-carousel-layout-in-android.html)
- [CarouselLayoutManager for RecyclerView](https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager)
- [Start my RecyclerView Horizontal Carousel from the center item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52317646/7666442)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use a `layout_gravity` in the `LinearLayout`?

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

**Before adding** `layout_gravity:center`

See the result (Blueprint view):
[image: basic LinearLayout gravity]

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
```

**After adding** `layout_gravity:center`

See the result (Blueprint view):
[image: LinearLayout with layout_gravity:center]

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
```

Comment: This actually achieves the look i want, but i can't scroll to the left (number 1) anymore

Answer (score 1):

So I don't think you can do it in xml.

My suggestion would be to do it in code. So after setContentView() in an Activity or in onViewCreated() in a Fragment, you can measure the width of the whole scrollview, divide it by 2, and then use the method [smoothScrollBy(int dx, int dy)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html#smoothScrollBy(int,%20int)) of your horizontalScrollView, or [scrollBy(int dx, int dy)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollBy(int,%20int)) if you don't it to be animated.

To get the width of the scrollview you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4989894/1386160). Just make sure you pass the correct units to the methods, either pixels, dps, etc.

If you need to transform the units then you can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9563438/1386160).

Comment: I tried doing `val scrollView:HorizontalScrollView = findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView)
        scrollView.smoothScrollBy(scrollView.getChildAt(1).width/2,0)` but it says that `getChildAt(1)` is `null`. Maybe because it is inside the Linear Layout?

Comment: You need to do `getChildAt(0)` since the only view inside the layout is the linear layout.

Comment: I tried that right after `getChildAt(1)` but it doesn't seem to affect the layout at all

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail So I would suggest to try to do a successful smoothscroll before trying to get the dimensions of the inner layout. Because now it's not clear if the problem is with the scroll or with getting the dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

I had as same task like you have, to **center the item in scroll view**

I did if just changing in layour scroll view

Try to **replace you scroll view with**

https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView

```
  <com.yarolegovich.discretescrollview.DiscreteScrollView
  android:id="@+id/picker"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:dsv_orientation="horizontal|vertical" />
```

Let me know if get success

Answer (score 0):

For this behaviour you should use `ViewPager` or `ViewPager2`(which is basically a `RecyclerView` with `SnapHelper` included)

I will show how to do it with a regular `ViewPager`

so the pager settings for carousel should be like this

```
pager.apply{
            // Set current item to the middle page so we can fling to both
            // directions left and right
            currentItem = 1

            // Necessary or the pager will only have one extra page to show
            // make this at least however many pages you can see
            offscreenPageLimit = 3

            // Set margin for pages as a negative number, so a part of next and
            // previous pages will be showed
            // Calculate here a value you need
            pageMargin = -((3f / 4f) * App.screenWidth).toInt()
        }
```

While the adapted should implement `ViewPager.PageTransformer`

```
class CarouselPagerAdapter : PagerAdapter(), ViewPager.PageTransformer {

...

  companion object {
        val NO_SCALE = 1.0f
        val SMALL_SCALE_DOWN = 0.1f
        val DIFF_SCALE = NO_SCALE - SMALL_SCALE_DOWN

        val FULL_OPACITY = 255
        val LOW_OPACITY = 5
        val DIFF_OPACITY = FULL_OPACITY - LOW_OPACITY

        val NO_TRANSLATION = 0f
        val TRANSLATION_Y = 100f
        val DIFF_TRANSLATION_Y = TRANSLATION_Y - NO_TRANSLATION
    }

    override fun transformPage(page: View, position: Float) {
        val scalableLayout = page.item_child_wrapper
        val animatableLayout = page.child_name_wrapper
        var scale = NO_SCALE
        var opacity = FULL_OPACITY
        var translationY = NO_TRANSLATION
        if (position > 0) {
            scale -= position * DIFF_SCALE
            opacity -= (position * DIFF_OPACITY).toInt()
            translationY -= (position * DIFF_TRANSLATION_Y)
        } else {
            scale += position * DIFF_SCALE
            opacity += (position * DIFF_OPACITY).toInt()
            translationY += (position * DIFF_TRANSLATION_Y)
        }
        if (scale < 0) scale = 0f
        if (opacity < 0) opacity = 0
        if (opacity > 255) opacity = 255
        scalableLayout.setScale(scale)
        scalableLayout.setOpacity(opacity)
        animatableLayout.setScale(scale)
        animatableLayout.setTranslation(0f, translationY)
    }



}
```

This is my old code so it should be modernized somehow and it works also with opacity and transitions of elements - but I think you will figure how to use it.

Hope it helps.