# How to create this type of animation in android

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I want to make this type of animation in android app like this :

[image]

I have some images in array like :

```
String[] imageArr = new String[]{"Url 1","Url 2","Url 3","Url 4","Url 5", "and more"};
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, you better check GitHub

Comment: Refer this
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35309710/zoom-central-image-recycler-view)

Comment: Please provide me some more info related to this

Comment: That looks like an image carousel. Search for "android carousel" and you should find info that will help you. You can also look at [MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/carousel).

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883849/3d-carousel-in-android

Comment: thanks for your help @Cheticamp and Android Geek, but can you help me in my case how can I achieve that