# Horizontal Scrolling RecyclerView with one scroll at a time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a Horizontal scrolling recycler view with only one scroll at a time.

I've used following LinearSnapHelper to centralize the view

```
public LinearSnapHelper getSnapHelper() {
    return new LinearSnapHelper() {
        @Override
        public int findTargetSnapPosition(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager, int velocityX, int velocityY) {
            View centerView = findSnapView(layoutManager);
            if (centerView == null)
                return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;

            int position = layoutManager.getPosition(centerView);
            int targetPosition = -1;
            if (layoutManager.canScrollHorizontally()) {
                if (velocityX < 0) {
                    targetPosition = position - 1;
                } else {
                    targetPosition = position + 1;
                }
            }

            if (layoutManager.canScrollVertically()) {
                if (velocityY < 0) {
                    targetPosition = position - 1;
                } else {
                    targetPosition = position + 1;
                }
            }

            final int firstItem = 0;
            final int lastItem = layoutManager.getItemCount() - 1;
            targetPosition = Math.min(lastItem, Math.max(targetPosition, firstItem));
            return targetPosition;
        }
    };
}
```

And then I've attached my horizontal recycler view to snaphelper as follow :

```
getSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(accountSelectionRecyclerView);
```

This works near perfect and centralize item as expected.

But I want to restrict my recycler view to scroll only one item at a time.

To achieve that I've created a custom recycler view to control the fling of the my recycler but still it has no effect and I can able to scroll to two,three items if I swipe with full force.

```
public class HorizontalRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    public HorizontalRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public HorizontalRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public HorizontalRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean fling(int velocityX, int velocityY) {
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) getLayoutManager();

        int lastVisibleView = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        int firstVisibleView = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        View firstView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstVisibleView);
        View lastView = linearLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(lastVisibleView);


        int leftMargin = (DeviceDetailsSingleton.getInstance().getScreenWidth() - lastView.getWidth()) / 2;
        int rightMargin = (DeviceDetailsSingleton.getInstance().getScreenWidth() - firstView.getWidth()) / 2 + firstView.getWidth();
        int leftEdge = lastView.getLeft();
        int rightEdge = firstView.getRight();
        int scrollDistanceLeft = leftEdge - leftMargin;
        int scrollDistanceRight = rightMargin - rightEdge;

        if (velocityX > 0)
            smoothScrollBy(scrollDistanceLeft, 0);
        else
            smoothScrollBy(-scrollDistanceRight, 0);

        return true;
    }
}
```

With normal swipe speed it's working perfectly.

Comment: refer this : https://github.com/harjot-oberai/MusicDNA/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/sdsmdg/harjot/MusicDNA/snappyrecyclerview or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370289/snappy-scrolling-in-recyclerview

Comment: please have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/42128379/3086769

Comment: @whit3hawks I've already tried PagerSnapHelper, That snaps the centralized view as expected but it allows to scroll more than an item with a force full swipe.

Comment: Have you found a way yet? I also has this issue.