# How to get an Item of Recyclerview when scroll stopped?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I have a Recyclerview inside Scrollview, I want to store item details of Recyclerview where scroll stopped.

I have a xml like,

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White">

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tile_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/news_feed_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have added ScrollListener for recyclerview. But As I'm using parent Scrollview for the activity, recyclerview's ScrollListener is not getting called.
I tried changing parent scrollview to NestedScrollView then recyclerview is scrolling as a one item at once but i want scroll to be freely. Like scrolling our contacts.

## Issue : When I scroll, Parent ScrollView getting scrolled and I don't have any control on my recyclerview. So It's difficult to figure out which item of recyclerview is visible once scroll stopped.

Basically I want to code without changing my XML.

Comment: You could try to get the visible items of the `recyclerview` ?

Comment: "It's not working" is not a good description of what is going on. What does the above code do? Does it save the first completely visible item *before* scrolling in a variable?

Comment: Thanks for identifying, I have edited the question, hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to store item details of Recyclerview where scroll stopped.

When scroll stops, scroll state transitions into idle state. However, idle state is the state *before and after* scroll. Therefore you are looking for a transition into idle state **after settling state**.

Do it like this:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    boolean scrolled;
    int[] displayedPositions;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
            scrolled = true;
        } else if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && scrolled) {
            scrolled = false;
            int[] into = new int[//number of spans];
            displayedPositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPositions(into)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: RecyclerView.OnScrollListener is not getting called as I'm using ScrollView as a parent view.

Comment: Use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` and add `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to the XML of your `RecyclerView`. This will, however, break view recycling.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private int overallXScrol = 0;

//...
mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            overallXScroll = overallXScroll + dx;

            Log.i("check","overall->" + overallXScroll);

        }
    });
```

Comment: This code will never execute, i have tested. It will not execute the Scroll listener of recyclerview because we have parent scrollview.

Comment: add this line : recycler_view.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); and i have edited my answer , try it once.may it helps you

Comment: Not Working, onScrolled will called only once when recyclerview is populating. I want every scroll to be captured. I have tried your way. It's not working.

Comment: have a look to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370289/snappy-scrolling-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

try `NestedScrollView` instead `scrollview` like below

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White">

<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tile_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/news_feed_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just we need to change layout. I'm using CoordinatorLayout as a parent view. And Now I'm able to use onScrollListener of recyclerview.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/tile_view_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>              

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/news_feed_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```