# Jetpack Compose LazyRow scroll with snap only to start of next or previous element

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is there a way to horizontally scroll only to start or specified position of previous or next element with Jetpack Compose?

[Snappy scrolling in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370289/snappy-scrolling-in-recyclerview)

Comment: this is not yet supported, you can follow [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/166590434) for updates

Comment: Well, yes there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the scrolling direction like so

```
@Composable
private fun LazyListState.isScrollingUp(): Boolean {
    var previousIndex by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemIndex) }
    var previousScrollOffset by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) }
    return remember(this) {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (previousIndex != firstVisibleItemIndex) {
                previousIndex > firstVisibleItemIndex
            } else {
                previousScrollOffset >= firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            }.also {
                previousIndex = firstVisibleItemIndex
                previousScrollOffset = firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            }
        }
    }.value
}
```

Of course, you will need to create a `rememberLazyListState()`, and then pass it to the list as a parameter.

Then, based upon the scrolling direction, you can call `lazyListState.scrollTo(lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex + 1)` in a coroutine (if the user is scrolling right), and appropriate calls for the other direction.

Comment: can you provide more detailed example please how to use your code to achieve snapping behavior for lazryRow ?

Comment: Hello Hospes, appologies for the late reply. I am afraid I do not know of the exact implementation of the same. I know it **can** be done, but exactly how, I guess you would need to reference to docs and do some serious study to grab that. Apparently the  OP already knew that, so upon my pointing in the direction, he could implement it on his own.

Answer (score 2):

(Example for a horizontal LazyRow)

You could do a scroll to the next or previous item to create a snap effect. Check the offset of the first visible item to see which item of the list takes up more screen space and then scroll left or right to the most visible one.

```
@Composable
fun SnappyLazyRow() {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LazyRow(
        state = listState,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        content = {
            items(/*list of items*/) { index ->
                /* Item view */

                if(!listState.isScrollInProgress){
                    if(listState.isHalfPastItemLeft())
                        coroutineScope.scrollBasic(listState, left = true)
                    else
                        coroutineScope.scrollBasic(listState)

                    if(listState.isHalfPastItemRight())
                        coroutineScope.scrollBasic(listState)
                    else
                        coroutineScope.scrollBasic(listState, left = true)
                }
            }
        })
}

private fun CoroutineScope.scrollBasic(listState: LazyListState, left: Boolean = false){
    launch {
        val pos = if(left) listState.firstVisibleItemIndex else listState.firstVisibleItemIndex+1
        listState.animateScrollToItem(pos)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun LazyListState.isHalfPastItemRight(): Boolean {
    return firstVisibleItemScrollOffset > 500
}

@Composable
private fun LazyListState.isHalfPastItemLeft(): Boolean {
    return firstVisibleItemScrollOffset <= 500
}
```

Comment: What is the 500 for?