# Snap to an index Lazyrow

Tags: list, android-jetpack-compose, snapping

I am making a calendar with the help of a lazyRow. I now have the problem that I want the row to snap to the index after a certain scroll amount so it shouldn't be possible to be stuck in between indexes. Is there a way to do that?

```
    LazyRow(state = calendarViewModel.listState, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        calendarYears.forEach {
            items(it.months.count()) { index ->
                calendarViewModel.onEvent(CalendarEvent.ClickedMenuItem(index))
                CalendarRowItem(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth(),
                    calendarSize = it.months[index].amountOfDays,
                    initWeekday = it.months[index].startDayOfMonth.ordinal,
                    textColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondaryVariant,
                    clickedColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                    textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body1
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use the `HorizontalPager` from accompanist library which has this fling behavior out-of-the-box and uses `LazyRow` internally.
https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/pager

Comment: is there no way to do it with built in functions from jetpack compose

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68884340/15880865) might help

Comment: Do you want to snap to the first visible index? or one view per screen like a pager?

Comment: one view per screen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `HorizontalPager` from [accompanist library](https://github.com/google/accompanist/tree/main/pager) which provides this fling behavior out-of-the-box and it uses `LazyRow` internally.

Another option could be use the [Snapper library](https://chrisbanes.github.io/snapper/) created by [@chris-banes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474997/chris-banes)

Add the dependency in your `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "dev.chrisbanes.snapper:snapper:<version>"
}
```

and use it in your `LazyRow`.

```
val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

LazyRow(
    state = lazyListState,
    flingBehavior = rememberSnapperFlingBehavior(lazyListState),
) {
    // content
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How did you get the first item to snap to the middle of the screen? I've tried using the Snapper library and the first item doesn't scroll beyond the left edge of the LazyRow.

Comment: I'm using `BoxWithConstraints` to get the screen width. Then then I'm using a `Layout` to place it in the center... See the full code of the example above [here](https://github.com/nglauber/JetpackComposePlayground/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/nglauber/jetpackcomposeplayground/screens/RowSnapperScreen.kt)

Answer (score 17):

Starting with compose [`1.3.0`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.3.0) you can use the [`FlingBehavior`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/snapping/SnapFlingBehavior) that performs snapping of items to a given position:

```
val state = rememberLazyListState()

LazyRow(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    state = state,
    flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(lazyListState = state)
) {
  //item content
}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to snap my starting item, the first visible item and not the middle one, is there any way to do that sir?

Comment: @zaidkhan check out my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77005797/958025

Comment: This gets me 

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: AnimationVector cannot contain a NaN. AnimationVector1D: value = NaN.
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of Gabriele's answer, for snapping based on first visible item   (side snapping to the start) we need to do the following:

```
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
val positionInLayout: Density.(Float, Float) -> Float = { _, _ ->
    // This value tells where to snap on the x axis within the viewport
    // Setting it to 0 results in snapping of the first visible item to the left side (or right side if RTL)
    0f
}
val snappingLayout = remember(scrollState) { SnapLayoutInfoProvider(scrollState, positionInLayout) }
val flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(snappingLayout)
LazyRow(
    modifier = modifier,
    state = scrollState,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 1.5f.u()),
    flingBehavior = flingBehavior,
    content = {}
)
```

Comment: Unable to pass positionLayout to SnapLayoutInfoProvider as the expected type is SnapLayoutInfoProvider

Answer (score 2):

```
val centerItemIndex by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        val layoutInfo = listState.layoutInfo
        val visibleItems = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
        val viewportCenter = (layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset + layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset) / 2

        visibleItems.minByOrNull { abs((it.offset + it.size / 2) - viewportCenter) }?.index ?: 0
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try this brother