# Android Jetpack compose with carousel layout

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to develop carousel UI that starts in the middle of the screen at the bottom and when we click on next item it automatically come in the middle. I am using `LazyRow` and using `Layout` with `measurePolicy`.

```
  Layout(
                    content = { itemContent(item, itemModifier) },
                    measurePolicy = { measurables, constraints ->
                        val placeable = measurables.first().measure(constraints)
                        // maxWidth is from the BoxWithConstraints
                        val maxWidthInPx = maxWidth.roundToPx()
                        // Box width
                        val itemWidth = placeable.width
                        // Calculating the space for the first and last item
                        val startSpace =
                            if (index == 0) (maxWidthInPx - itemWidth) / 2 else 0
                        val endSpace =
                            if (index == data.lastIndex) (maxWidthInPx - itemWidth) / 2 else 0
                        // The width of the box + extra space
                        val width = startSpace + placeable.width + endSpace
                        layout(width, placeable.height) {
                            // Placing the Box in the right X position
                            val x = startSpace
                            placeable.place(x, 0)
                        }
                    })
            }
```

This is working for first element but clicking on next element, the selected element go to the start of the screen, instead it should be in the middle.

Comment: Does this answer helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71901039/snap-to-an-index-lazyrow/71902645#71902645