# Unable to import rememberSnapFlingBehavior

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, importerror

I'm trying to implement [this behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74867752) in my compose application, but when I import the required function with the following import statement, I get an `Unresolved reference: snapping` error from Android Studio.

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.snapping.rememberSnapFlingBehavior
```

In my `build.gradle` file I've noticed that the `compose_version` and the `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion` variables were both set to 1.2.0 by default, so I tried setting those to 1.3.1, but it didn't fix the issue.

Here's my current `build.gradle` (Project) file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.3.1'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
```

and the `build.gradle` (App) file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.app'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.1'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

What else can I try to fix this?

Comment: Can you share your app + project build.gradle files?

Comment: @susosaurus I've updated my post to include them

Comment: Thanks! I think you need to directly include the foundation dependency in your app build.gradle file: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Compose Foundation dependency in your module level `build.gradle` file.

```bash
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.3.1")
}
```